# Django testing won't run because of syntax error

Tags: django, python-3.x, unicode, pycharm

When I run my tests I get a syntax error: SyntaxError: `(unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 0: invalid start byte`

The cause of this seems to be that I use a § in a string on line 62. I'm using python 3.4.2 for the project and have used § elsewhere without getting a error. I got a friend to open the project as well, on his screen the § in tests.py showed up as question marks, but this was only in the test files, in the other places it had been used it showed up as normal. I got him to change the § that were showing up as question marks to § on his pc and it worked, which is really weird. How would I go about fixing something like this on my computer though? I can't really get him to load up the file and insert special character every time I want to use them in tests.

edit: So I found out pycharm for some reason had set only tests.py to a encoding other than utf-8. I changed this to utf-8 and it then showed the § I had written as question marks. However swapping them out for § did not work for me. The reason is that for some reason even though the encoding is set to utf-8, pycharm still displays latin1 for me and type latin1 characters instead of utf-8. I've tested on 2 other computers (1 mac, and 1 windows 8.1 same as the one I have problems with) where it correctly displays utf-8. On those computers my § still appear as question marks, but if i change it on the other computer it now appears as Â§ on the computer with the problem. So my problem now is to get pycharm to properly use UTF-8 instead of latin 1.

Comment: You have the line # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
in the top of your file?

Comment: You don't need to specify encoding for Python 3. Are you sure the file actually uses UTF-8? “§” is `0xA7` in latin1 but `0xC2 0xA7` in UTF-8.

Comment: I tried remaking the file, but that didn't do it. So i opened it in notepad++ and under encoding it says ANSI, i tried changing that to both of the UTF-8 settings and it still didn't work.

Comment: Actually changing it in pycharm also didn't help (in settings->file encoding, for some reason tests.py was the only file that didn't auto to utf-8), now the § turned up as question marks, and i replaced them and it still crashed. I got my friend to change them for me and on my screen they now look like this: Â§. When i try to run test with Â§ everything works. so confused right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found the problem. as patrys sugested in a comment the file didn't use UTF-8 as encoding. To change that in pycharm I had to go to file->settings->editor->file encodings and change the file encoding for tests to utf-8. After I did that I had to go into the file and re eddit the § as they have now turned into question marks. However it still didn't work. I found out that I also have to change it to UTF-8 down in the right corner of pycharm. For some reason tests is the only .py file that was affected by this (even though I deleted the original tests.py file and remade it).